# Is accelerated database recovery available in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, recovery, sql-server-2019

SQL Server 2019 CTP introduced a new feature – [accelerated database recovery](https://www.sqlshack.com/accelerated-database-recovery-instant-rollback-and-database-recovery/). But then something strange started to happen:

- If we look at [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/sql-database/sql-database-accelerated-database-recovery) about this feature, we would see no mention of
  SQL Server 2019 – there’s Azure DB only.
- If we look at [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
  description, we would see no mention of
  is_accelerated_database_recovery_on column, while in fact, it exists
- Same thing about accelerated_database_recovery [database option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
- However, [feature matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15) shows ADR available for Standard and Enterprise SQL Server editions.

On the one hand, enabling ADR could benefit with faster transaction rollback and lesser startup time.

On the other hand, feature seems undocumented. Therefore, it’s behavior is unpredictable. If something goes wrong with transaction log, I could literally lose some data.

So, does anybody knows: can I rely on ADR using SQL Server 2019? Is it postponed due to some instability or it is just a glitch in documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation page link in your question is specific to Azure SQL Database. Note Azure in the url:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/sql-database/sql-database-accelerated-database-recovery.
```

The [Accelerated database recovery page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts) in the general documentation shows ADR is included in SQL 2019 and Azure SQL Database.